# Restricting Access to a webpage using python flask stripe payment

Tags: python, flask, stripe-payments

I have a basic flask app, where I charge customers to view a page

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import stripe

app = Flask(__name__)

pub_key = 'pk_test_999999999'
secret_key = 'sk_test_999999'

stripe.api_key = secret_key


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', pub_key=pub_key)


@app.route('/thank_you')
def thanks():
    return render_template('thanks.html')


@app.route('/pay', methods=['POST'])
def pay():

    customer = stripe.Customer.create(
        email=request.form['stripeEmail'],
        source=request.form['stripeToken']
    )

    charge = stripe.Charge.create(
        customer=customer.id,
        amount=19900,
        currency='usd',
        description='The Product'
    )

    return redirect(url_for('thanks'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

What I am trying to do is restrict access to the thank you page I want no one to access the thank_you by typing the whole url in the browser only paying customers get to see the thank you page even if someone type the whole url www.example.com/thank_you it will redirect to you haven't paid please pay

I thought about adding a login page and having a decorator only login customers, I did not like the idea I don't like to create such a barrier I want no customer info to deal with just pay and access page

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Remember this is not completely secure. As I don’t know how your ids and tokens are generated. But it’s just for the sake of simplicity.

If you want something more secure check flask sessions or flask login packages.

```
customers_payed = []

@app.route('/pay', methods=['POST'])
def pay():

    customer = stripe.Customer.create(
        email=request.form['stripeEmail'],
        source=request.form['stripeToken']
    )

    charge = stripe.Charge.create(
        customer=customer.id,
        amount=19900,
        currency='usd',
        description='The Product'
    )
 # add customer id to list maybe hash it with its email and token you can make this as hard to guess as you want
    customers_payed.append(str(customer.id) + request.form['stripeToken'])

    return redirect(url_for('thanks', customer_id=customer.id, token= request.form['stripeToken']))


@app.route('/thank_you')
def thanks():
    customer_id = requests.args.get(“customer_id”)
    token = requests.args.get(“token”)
    # check if its in the list, maybe pop it if customer is only allowed once
    if (customer_id+token) in customers_payed:
        return render_template('thanks.html')
    else:
        return redirect(url_for(“replace with error page”))
```